# nginx SSL proxy for S3 not work

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

I have a problem with nginx to SSL protocol, i use like proxy for amazon S3, HTTP protocol works perfectly, but i nedd ssl access, i have configured in this way:

```
resolver                   172.16.0.23 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout           10s;
proxy_cache_path           /tmp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=S3CACHE:10m inactive=48h max_size=1000m;
proxy_temp_path            /tmp/cache/temp;
server {
  listen       80;
  listen       443;
  ssl           on;
  ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/my.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/my.key;
  server_name  my.domain.it;
  location / {
    try_files $uri @s3cache;
  }

  location @s3cache{
    proxy_cache            S3CACHE;
    proxy_cache_valid      200 48h;
    proxy_cache_valid      403 60m;
    proxy_pass http://my.domain.it.s3-external-3.amazonaws.com;
  }
}
```

But don't work, firefox says "ssl_error_rx_record_too_long", google chrome instead "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

Answer (score 0):

Ok i resolved, the problem is the certificate that have a password, nginx don't start, removed the password and it's ok

Thank's all